# Working with Incomplete Data in Perl DBI

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have a table which looks like this:

```
tagname   username    photos

john    John Walker    -

john       -         123.jpg
```

note: "-" denotes a blank here i.e., nothing.

When I'm doing the following statement, I'm getting blank results.

```
"SELECT * FROM tableA where tagname=?"
```

Though, following statement is giving the right result as "123.jpg"

```
"SELECT photos FROM tableA WHERE tagname=?"
```

But, following statement is is giving blank again. Doing two separate SQL statements is also not working.

```
"SELECT username & photos FROM tableA WHERE tagname=?"
```

I want to club all the username that match a tagname, into @ArrayA and all photos, that match the same tagname into @ArrayB.

Sample code is as follows.

```
my $tag = 'john';

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq(SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE tagname=? ));
$sth->execute($tag) or die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";

my @ArrayA = undef;
while (my $ABC = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    push (@ArrayA, $ABC);
    }

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print @ArrayA;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fetchrow_array](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.632/DBI.pm#fetchrow_array) returns an array.

Change your while loop to:

```
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    push @ArrayA, \@row;
}
```

To view the content of `@ArrayA` use this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@ArrayA);
```

Comment: I will try this out in the morning, will let you know.

Comment: I got a result similar to: ARRAY(0x101f8e0) ARRAY(0x10cc638) instead of plain text I was expecting, any ideas for improvement?

Comment: btw, which SQL statement should go with your method of while loop?

Comment: @AhmadBilal: use Data::Dumper to dump the array. The sql statement isn't modified. See my edit.

Comment: K thanks. I will try that, but is there a way to do this without Data:Dumper? I don't use that module in general (despite its helpfulness), so I would love not to call another module for a single usage.

Comment: @AhmadBilal: Ther're no simplest way to dump such array of array. You don't have to install anything, Data::Dumper is a core module.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting blank field as result since one of the field is NULL. The result you will get for the query for each row will be just `0`. You can do concatenation to achieve your requirement.

> SELECT CONCAT( username , photos ) AS photo_name FROM tableA WHERE tagname=?

I think, the query

> SELECT username & photos FROM tableA where tagname=?

is a wrong choice for your requirement.

Now you can write your program as follows :

```
my $tag = 'john';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT CONCAT( username , photos ) AS photo_name FROM tableA WHERE tagname=?});
$sth->execute($tag) or die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";

my @ArrayA = undef;
while (my $ABC = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
     push (@ArrayA, $ABC->{photo_name});
}
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print @ArrayA;
```

Comment: I have never used CONCAT, is it supported in DBI-Perl?

Comment: You can execute any SQL query using DBI-Perl. "CONCAT" which I wrote here is just a MySql function. So it is supported in DBI-Perl.

Comment: Please check my new edit in which I include. Hope this program will give you the desired output.